# Efficient data structure to maintain sorted order after updating existing elements?

Tags: sorting, data-structures

So my problem is as follows: I have a large amount of nodes (users), each with an associated score. These scores are frequently updated, and I would like to be able to retrieve the list of users at any time sorted by score.

Currently I am just sorting when asking to retrieve, but I would rather have some data structure which can update the nodes and keep them sorted enough for efficient retrieval (linear or better).

I have considered using a balanced BST but is there a more clever and efficient solution? (I am working in C#, but I'd rather have a general solution)

Comment: I usually check this source to make the best choice of data structure depending of the situation, I hope it helps.http://bigocheatsheet.com/

Comment: How many users? Are the scores within a range? Some ideas I have are not super space friendly, and others are better when there are bounds on the scores.

Comment: As a more general principle, you should specify in finer detail some points such as the maximum possible number of users(or at least expected number of users) as well as the expected frequency of the "sorted scores retrieval" operation or what you consider to be efficient. I may say that a balanced BST could work, but without a bound on the number of users and a better sense of what you call efficient, I may be incorrect. (e.g. O(logN) score update time may be too inefficient to you)